# Преимущества RxJava+RxAndroid перед AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, rxjava

Везде написано, что RxJava(+RxAndroid) лучше AsyncTask, а в чём реальные преимущества RxJava(+RxAndroid) перед AsyncTask?

Comment: меня также это интересует)

Comment: Вместо лапши из колбеков и т.п. красивые чейны из вызовов асинхронных методов.

Answer (score 1):

RxJava - в основном используется если у вас есть множество задач, вы можете поместить их в последовательность, которую вы знаете, когда закончите, а следующий вот-вот начнется (Вы можете удобно управлять этим стеком потоков при необходимости ). А AsyncTask, используйте если у вас более одного запуска, так как у вас нет гарантии того, какая задача будет выполнена в первую очередь, а это может чередовать много ошибок. Если вы заботитесь о порядке, RxJava позволяет вам выполнять последовательные вызовы.

Что касается утечек памяти, мы можем иметь AsyncTask как внутренний класс активности. Теперь, поскольку он связан с активностью, когда действие уничтожается, контекст все еще висит вокруг и не будет собираться мусором, это часть утечки памяти.

Здесь RxJava может помочь. если какие-либо ошибки возникают вообще, мы можем вызвать подписчиков onError и сделать нужные нам действия.Так что если одна задача сойдет и Async если много то в сторону Rx.

Comment: Лучше бы было с примерами.

Comment: Не убедили. Разве AsynTask'и выполняются не последовательно? Что значит знать, когда закончится задача? В AsynTask тоже можно ошибки обрабатывать.

Comment: @elik, а если в той же активити вы не отпишите подписчика, утечки не будет?